# Как обработать блоки списка li?

Tags: css, html

Высота блоков разная, зависит от объема текста. Как сделать так, чтоб блоки ниже занимали пустующую площадь выше? Или есть ли другие советы?

http://www.cssdesk.com/UfLqS

```css
.spisok h1 {
  background-color: white;
  font-size:14px;
  
  }
.spisok p {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius:15px;
  }
.spisok li {
  list-style-type:none;
  width:200px;
  padding:5px;
  margin:6px;
  float:left;
  border: 4px double black;
  border-radius:15px;
  }
  .clearfloat { 
  clear: both;
 height: 0;
 line-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="spisok">
<ul>
<li><h1><a href=35-mejdunarodnie-normi-istochniki.html>Международные нормы. Источники их формирования.</a></h1><p>Эта глава исследует универсальную юрисдикцию в международных нормативных источниках. Выделяются между многосторонними международными нормами договоров, резолюции межгосударственных органов, и официальные проекты и исследования. <a href=35-mejdunarodnie-normi-istochniki.html>подробнее</a><p>

  </li>
  
  
  <li><h1><a href=34-princip-universalnosti.html>Принцип универсальности заключает в себе 3 разных понятия</a></h1><p>Принцип универсальности заключает в себе 3 разных понятия <a href=34-princip-universalnosti.html>подробнее</a><p>

 </li><li><h1><a href=33-Kolliziya-yurisdiktsiy-v-dele-o-nesostoyatelnosti-kompanii-Eurofood.html>Коллизия юрисдикций в деле о несостоятельности компании Eurofood</a></h1><p>Феномен трансграничной несостоятельности, при которой разброс активов и мест деятельности должника вызывает столкновение интересов и требований, существует с тех пор, как существует экономическая мобильность хозяйствующих субъектов, чья деятельность выходит за рамки одного государства, приобретая тем самым международный характер. <a href=33-Kolliziya-yurisdiktsiy-v-dele-o-nesostoyatelnosti-kompanii-Eurofood.html>подробнее</a><p>

 </li><li><h1><a href=32-YUrisdiktsiya-i-megdunarodnie-normi.html>Юрисдикция и международные нормы</a></h1><p>Односторонний принцип ограничения универсальности также поднимает вопрос совместимости с международным нормами уголовным судом. Как сначала подразумевалось, это понятие принцип универсальности было заменой несуществующему международным нормам уголовному суду, идеалистическому решению несовершенной структуры международной нормы правопорядка. <a href=32-YUrisdiktsiya-i-megdunarodnie-normi.html>подробнее</a><p>

 </li><li><h1><a href=31-chto-takoe-byurokratiya.html>Что такое бюрократия</a></h1><p><a href="31-chto-takoe-byurokratiya.html">Что такое бюрократия?</a> <a href=31-chto-takoe-byurokratiya.html>подробнее</a><p>

 </li><li><h1><a href=30-Krim-Rissiya-vmeste.html>Переехать в Россию не меняя место жительства</a></h1><p>Больше года назад жители Крыма (была в составе Украины) приняли участие в референдуме и определили свое будущее в составе той или иной страны, то есть в России. Насколько это важное событие обсуждать не собираюсь, здесь хотелось б рассказать о юридической стороне столь важного события в жизни граждан Крыма. 
 <a href=30-Krim-Rissiya-vmeste.html>подробнее</a><p>

 </li><li><h1><a href=29-xigins-diplomaticheskaya-zashhita-gosudarstva.html>Хигинс: дипломатическая защита государства</a></h1><p>Хиггинс критиковал использование высказывания Барселонскои Корпорации в качестве авторитетного источника универсальной юрисдикции: о нем говорится так, как будто оно обеспечивает руководство для современного применения принципа универсальности юрисдикции – так, как будто суд подтвердил универсальную юрисдикцию в отношении каждого из этих правонарушений. <a href=29-xigins-diplomaticheskaya-zashhita-gosudarstva.html>подробнее</a><p>

 </li><li><h1><a href=28-odnostoronnij-princip-ogranichennosti-universalnosti.html>Односторонний принцип ограниченности универсальности</a></h1><p>Односторонний принцип ограниченности универсальности более не нуждается в связи с государством, в котором находится суд. Единственный критерии – международные нормы – право характер преступлении юрисдикции на самом дела «универсально», так как любое государство может в одностороннем порядке инициировать расследование, даже заочно. Экстрадиция подозреваемого приветствуется, что бы обеспечить персональную юрисдикцию в суде. <a href=28-odnostoronnij-princip-ogranichennosti-universalnosti.html>подробнее</a><p>

 </li><li><h1><a href=27-yurisdikciya-gosudarstva-nakazat-ili-net.html>Юрисдикция государства: наказать или нет</a></h1><p>Созданные <a href="26-nakazyvat-prestupnika-kotoryj-nam-ne-meshaet.html">таким образом права и обязательства</a> являются двусторонними между государством, где находится преступник и государством, которое непосредственно связано с правонарушением. Положения политики Гроция и Де Ваттеля не санкционируют право третьих государств наказывать <b>правонарушителя.</b> <a href=27-yurisdikciya-gosudarstva-nakazat-ili-net.html>подробнее</a><p>

 </li><li><h1><a href=26-nakazyvat-prestupnika-kotoryj-nam-ne-meshaet.html>Наказывать преступника который нам не «мешает»?</a></h1><p>Де Ваттель поддерживает идей Гроцяи в своей работе «Права народов или принципы естественного права, применяемые к поведению и отношениям наций и суверенных государств». Как правило, только государство, на территории которого находится преступник, компетентно, «природа не дает людям или народам право накладывать наказание, кроме как в целях их защиты и безопасности…; отсюда вытекает, что мы не можем никого наказывать, только лишь тех, кто нам навредил, однако: <a href=26-nakazyvat-prestupnika-kotoryj-nam-ne-meshaet.html>подробнее</a></li>



</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставляйте код прямо в сообщение, а не ссылайтесь на внешние ресурсы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением. У меня ссылка вообще не открывается.

Comment: просто думал дать ссылку будет легче,

Comment: Вы можете использовать кнопку "Фрагмент кода" (Ctrl+M) для добавления кода. Это мини-JSFiddle прямо на сайте. А код нужно оформлять отступами в 4 пробела, как минимум.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно решение в самом общем виде, то вам поможет только flex. Он ещё не во всех браузерах идеально поддерживается, где-то требует префиксов, поэтому могут понадобиться CSS-препроцессоры, если хотите писать чистый код.

Решение на flex простое: сказать размещать элементы построчно, с переносом, с высотой элементов во всю высоту.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 6px;
  border: 4px double black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
h1 {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}
p {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><h1><a href=35-mejdunarodnie-normi-istochniki.html>Международные нормы. Источники их формирования.</a></h1><p>Эта глава исследует универсальную юрисдикцию в международных нормативных источниках. Выделяются между многосторонними международными нормами договоров, резолюции межгосударственных органов, и официальные проекты и исследования. <a href=35-mejdunarodnie-normi-istochniki.html>подробнее</a><p></li>
  <li><h1><a href=34-princip-universalnosti.html>Принцип универсальности заключает в себе 3 разных понятия</a></h1><p>Принцип универсальности заключает в себе 3 разных понятия <a href=34-princip-universalnosti.html>подробнее</a><p></li>
  <li><h1><a href=33-Kolliziya-yurisdiktsiy-v-dele-o-nesostoyatelnosti-kompanii-Eurofood.html>Коллизия юрисдикций в деле о несостоятельности компании Eurofood</a></h1><p>Феномен трансграничной несостоятельности, при которой разброс активов и мест деятельности должника вызывает столкновение интересов и требований, существует с тех пор, как существует экономическая мобильность хозяйствующих субъектов, чья деятельность выходит за рамки одного государства, приобретая тем самым международный характер. <a href=33-Kolliziya-yurisdiktsiy-v-dele-o-nesostoyatelnosti-kompanii-Eurofood.html>подробнее</a><p></li>
  <li><h1><a href=32-YUrisdiktsiya-i-megdunarodnie-normi.html>Юрисдикция и международные нормы</a></h1><p>Односторонний принцип ограничения универсальности также поднимает вопрос совместимости с международным нормами уголовным судом. Как сначала подразумевалось, это понятие принцип универсальности было заменой несуществующему международным нормам уголовному суду, идеалистическому решению несовершенной структуры международной нормы правопорядка. <a href=32-YUrisdiktsiya-i-megdunarodnie-normi.html>подробнее</a><p></li>
  <li><h1><a href=31-chto-takoe-byurokratiya.html>Что такое бюрократия</a></h1><p><a href="31-chto-takoe-byurokratiya.html">Что такое бюрократия?</a> <a href=31-chto-takoe-byurokratiya.html>подробнее</a><p></li>
  <li><h1><a href=30-Krim-Rissiya-vmeste.html>Переехать в Россию не меняя место жительства</a></h1><p>Больше года назад жители Крыма (была в составе Украины) приняли участие в референдуме и определили свое будущее в составе той или иной страны, то есть в России. Насколько это важное событие обсуждать не собираюсь, здесь хотелось б рассказать о юридической стороне столь важного события в жизни граждан Крыма.<a href=30-Krim-Rissiya-vmeste.html>подробнее</a><p></li>
  <li><h1><a href=29-xigins-diplomaticheskaya-zashhita-gosudarstva.html>Хигинс: дипломатическая защита государства</a></h1><p>Хиггинс критиковал использование высказывания Барселонскои Корпорации в качестве авторитетного источника универсальной юрисдикции: о нем говорится так, как будто оно обеспечивает руководство для современного применения принципа универсальности юрисдикции – так, как будто суд подтвердил универсальную юрисдикцию в отношении каждого из этих правонарушений. <a href=29-xigins-diplomaticheskaya-zashhita-gosudarstva.html>подробнее</a><p></li>
  <li><h1><a href=28-odnostoronnij-princip-ogranichennosti-universalnosti.html>Односторонний принцип ограниченности универсальности</a></h1><p>Односторонний принцип ограниченности универсальности более не нуждается в связи с государством, в котором находится суд. Единственный критерии – международные нормы – право характер преступлении юрисдикции на самом дела «универсально», так как любое государство может в одностороннем порядке инициировать расследование, даже заочно. Экстрадиция подозреваемого приветствуется, что бы обеспечить персональную юрисдикцию в суде. <a href=28-odnostoronnij-princip-ogranichennosti-universalnosti.html>подробнее</a><p></li>
  <li><h1><a href=27-yurisdikciya-gosudarstva-nakazat-ili-net.html>Юрисдикция государства: наказать или нет</a></h1><p>Созданные <a href="26-nakazyvat-prestupnika-kotoryj-nam-ne-meshaet.html">таким образом права и обязательства</a> являются двусторонними между государством, где находится преступник и государством, которое непосредственно связано с правонарушением. Положения политики Гроция и Де Ваттеля не санкционируют право третьих государств наказывать <b>правонарушителя.</b> <a href=27-yurisdikciya-gosudarstva-nakazat-ili-net.html>подробнее</a><p></li>
  <li><h1><a href=26-nakazyvat-prestupnika-kotoryj-nam-ne-meshaet.html>Наказывать преступника который нам не «мешает»?</a></h1><p>Де Ваттель поддерживает идей Гроцяи в своей работе «Права народов или принципы естественного права, применяемые к поведению и отношениям наций и суверенных государств». Как правило, только государство, на территории которого находится преступник, компетентно, «природа не дает людям или народам право накладывать наказание, кроме как в целях их защиты и безопасности…; отсюда вытекает, что мы не можем никого наказывать, только лишь тех, кто нам навредил, однако: <a href=26-nakazyvat-prestupnika-kotoryj-nam-ne-meshaet.html>подробнее</a></li>
</ul>
```

С помощью float вы не получите нормального выравнивания по высоте, если высота может быть различная. Для исправления понадобится JavaScript.

С помощью table вы можете получить выравнивание элементов по высоте, но будет жёсткая привязка к количеству элементов в строке.

В общем и целом, эта задача нормально решается только с помощью flex. В остальных случаях придётся мириться с костылями либо на клиенте, либо на сервере.